# Confused with integration order

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to calculate  $\iint_A f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$ for some function where A is the area where $0\leq y\leq x \leq \infty$.

I computed $ \int_{y=0}^{x} \int_{x=y}^{\infty}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$ and got a wrong answer (checked it with WolframAlpha). My logic with the boundries - look at all $y$ values in the area. It's always between $y=0$ and $y=x$ right? or is it between $0$ and $\infty$? How can I know which is right? if integrating in $dxdy$ order maybe $y$ has to be bounded by numbers not functions? this is very confusing. for $y_0$, we see that $y\leq x \leq \infty$.

Comment: You have a differentiation variable boundary in the outer integral, so it cannot be evaluated.  Your boundaries should be $0\to x$ and $0\to\infty$...

Comment: Or if you need to compute $x$ first, then use $y\to\infty$ and $0\to\infty$.

Comment: So always the outer integral must be a number?

Comment: You should compute $\int_{y=0}^{\infty} \int_{x=y}^{\infty}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$  The upper limit on the outer integral is $\infty$.

Comment: Each integral has to resolve within its context, so the outermost has to resolve to any variables or constants not dependent on the integration, the next integral going inward can depend on the outermost variable, and so on.

Comment: @abiessu So first looking at $y$, it is going from 0 to $\infty$ as GEdgar wrote. But why not $0$ to $x$? both seem correct to me, that's my problem.  Then for constant $y_0$ we can see $x$ from $y$ to $\infty$, which I wrote correct in the post

Comment: If $y$ is evaluated first, then you use $y\in[0,x]$.  But if $y$ is evaluated second, that means the $x$ bounds were already based on $y$, so you can put $y\in[0,\infty)$.  The outermost integral is evaluated last, but written (reading left to right) first, so that is how I wrote down the bounds.

Comment: In $\int_{y=0}^x \int_{x=y}^\infty f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$, the variable $x$ in $\int_{x=y}^\infty f(x,y) \,dx$ is a dummy variable. It's scope begins and ends with this integral. Outside the integral, it is undefined. So the $\int_{y=0}^x$, being outside that integral, cannot depend upon this same $x$ used in the inner integral. It can only refer to some other variable named "$x$" as well, but defined in the greater context (always a poor practice to use the same name for two variables, even when one is a dummy). However you do not have such a variable defined, so the upper limit is meaningless.